# Lists the organic groups current user is not a member

Tags: views, organic-groups

I want to create a view that lists the groups user is not a member of.
Tried to add the filter criteria -:(author)user:current(no),but it displays the groups user is a member & only filters the  groups manage(created) by user. 
Views-:7.x-3.7
og-:7.x-2.3

Comment: what exactly u wanna go for.
CAn u elaborate....

Comment: I want to create the view that lists the groups & user should not be a member of(non-member) any listed groups.check this node https://drupal.org/node/596860.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view that lists all groups the current user is *not* a member of, but you need to develop your own custom Drupal module for it (if anybody knows of a simpler way, please share your knowledge).

The general idea is as follows: Create a view that lists *all* groups. In your custom module, implement the hook [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7). There, add a condition to the view's query that checks whether the current user is or isn't a member of a group.

You can create the view that lists *all* groups via the website, or implement it in your custom module as well. For the latter, you can get a rough idea from tutorials like [this](http://websmiths.co/blog/drupal-views-tutorials-exporting-views-code).

In the database, the memberships are stored in the table `og_membership`. The field `gid` refers to the group's node id in the `node` table. The user who is member of the group is referred as an "Entity". So for each membership, the field `entity_type` is "user", and `etid` is the user id. So, a user is a member of a group if there *exists* a record in `og_membership` with the user's id in `etid`, "user" as `entity_type` and the group's id as `gid`. The other way around, if a user is not member in a group, such a membership record *doesn't exist*. In plain SQL, you could say something like (for user id 123)

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title
FROM node AS n
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM og_membership AS m
  WHERE n.id=m.gid AND m.entity_type = "user" AND m.etid = 123
);
```

In your custom module, you need to add this `NOT EXISTS`-Condition to the view's query. To do that, you implement the hook [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7). The following is a rough idea of what the implementation should look like:

```
// the parameters are a reference to the view and the query, respectively
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  // get the current user's info from the global scope
  global $user;

  // alter only the query for the correct view, not for every view on the site
  if($view->name == "MY_VIEWS_NAME" && $view->current_display == "MY_CURRENT_DISPLAY") {
    // the subquery to check for memberships
    $member_query = "SELECT * FROM {og_membership} AS m WHERE m.entity_type = 'user' AND m.etid = :uid AND m.gid = node.id";
    // add a new expression to the WHERE part of your view's query
    $query->add_where_expression("AND", "NOT EXISTS (" . $member_query . ")", array(":uid" => $user->uid));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your View, using Drupal 7:

**RELATIONSHIPS**

```
OG membership: OG membership from Node group

(OG membership from node group) OG membership: User from OG membership
```

**FILTER CRITERIA**

```
(user from OG membership) User: Current (No)
```

Comment: But wouldn't that list groups the user *is* in, as long as any other user is that group as well? Because the filter "group membership has different user than the current user" would find those as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But is it possible to have an empty group?
But I agree, the solution is not perfect.